# Get all content between and including square brackets if it contains a string

Tags: php, regex

I have seen very similar questions to this but I think mine is slightly different.

I have a string like this

```
[map=”enabled”, lat=”53.155206″, long=”-2.078422″, zoom=”14″]
```

With regex, how can I get the string based on the following

- Is enclosed in square brackets
- Starts with map="enabled"

I would have thought it was something like this

```
\[(map=("enabled"))+\]
```

I have researched methods on matching an exact string inside the square brackets, but I get a bit confused when it comes to the `"` character and then grabbing the whole string until and including the closing bracket?

Comment: You can use: `/\[map=”enabled”[^]]*]/`

Comment: take care : `"` is not the same than `”`. Are you sure your string is exactly as the one you've posted?

Comment: @Cid yes, that is my exact string

Comment: See it working here: https://regex101.com/r/NnQH4H/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `map=”enabled”` is **right next to** opening `[` then you may use this regex with a negated character class:

```
/\[map=”enabled”[^]]*]/
```

[RegEx Demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/NnQH4H/1/)

However if `map=”enabled”` can be anywhere inside `[...]` then use:

```
/\[[^]]*?map=”enabled”[^]]*]/
```

[RegEx Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/NnQH4H/2)

Comment: Hi anubhava sir, `^\[map=”enabled”.*\]` is this regex will also be ok for OP's requirement, could you please let me know if  this approach is ok or not here   I tested in https://regex101.com/r/NnQH4H/1/

Comment: Yes that may also work but remember that `.*` is greedy and can match anything. So if there multiple instances of `[...]` then `.*` will match until last `]`

Comment: Sure thank you, I am actually going through a GREAT person's whose name's regex is `^[Aa][a-zA-Z]+[aA]$` posts to learn regex :) Thank you for guiding here.